# How to adjustment SeleniumLibrary to headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I have python code with selenium to run gui automation tests. I need to change the code to run in headless mode. I see that can do it by import webdriver and chrome options, but currently code using SeleniumLibrary and BrowserManagementKeywords. Is it possible to add headless option to SeleniumLibrary or I have to change the code to import webdriver?
This is the code I'm using:

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary, BrowserManagementKeywords, ScreenshotKeywords
    ctx: SeleniumLibrary = SeleniumLibrary()
    browser_ctx = BrowserManagementKeywords(ctx)
    browser_ctx.open_browser(TestConfiguration.LOGIN_URL, TestConfiguration.BROWSER)
```

Comment: Have you got a chance to look in this URL? - https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html

Comment: I update the code and add the option, but now I get an error that element doesn't found (when run without headless, it's find the element)

Comment: I update the code and add the options:--headless,  --disable-gpu, --window-size=1920x1080, --ignore-certificate-errors, --allow-running-insecure-content, and now open browser doesn't failed but when tried to find element, return with error that element doesn't found (when run without headless, it's find the element)

Comment: Try using `wait()` or use `time.sleep(10)` before finding the element. It will give time to load that particular element.